# How To pass value Linq to controller and pass to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have trouble showing data from models to the controller and is shown into the view.

Models Customer

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Train1.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> ListCustomer { get; set; }

        public void CustomerData()
        {
            ListCustomer.Add(new Customer { CustomerId = "C01", CustomerName = "Mike" });
            ListCustomer.Add(new Customer { CustomerId = "C02", CustomerName = "August" });
            ListCustomer.Add(new Customer { CustomerId = "C03", CustomerName = "Jhon" });
            ListCustomer.Add(new Customer { CustomerId = "C04", CustomerName = "Andie" });
        }
    }
}
```

Models CustomerOrders

```
namespace Train1.Models
{
    public class CustomerOrders
    {
        public static void GetCustomer() 
        {
            Customer cu = new Customer();
            cu.CustomerData();
            var ListCustomer = from r in cu.ListCustomer select r;
        }
    }
}
```

Controllers

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using train1.Models;

namespace train1.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customer
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CustomerOrders cust = new CustomerOrders();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your not passing a model to the view. And what does this have to do with linq?

Comment: Sorry, i update my question

Comment: What does your `CustomerOrders` class have do do with your question? No where do you call the `GetCustomer()` method, but it would be pointless anyway since it `void` - it does not return anything!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'd assume the OP is still learning the basics and `CustomerOrders` would represent a service, hence my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your View to receive the Model from the Controller, you need to pass it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(CustomerOrders.GetCustomer());
}
```

Also notice that `GetCustomer()` does not return the data, change it to:

```
public class CustomerOrders
{
    public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomer() 
    {
        Customer cu = new Customer();
        cu.CustomerData();
        // from r in cu.ListCustomer select r
        return cu.ListCustomer; //no need to use LinQ here
    }
}
```

Comment: i got it, but i want get from my linq query, i have updating my question,